# Applications losing focus for a few seconds in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, mouse, window-focus

Recently all of my applications keep losing focus every minute (or so) for a few seconds (then the window gets the focus back). It is very annoying, since I'm typing most of the time and get interrupted by this behavior. Things worked fine until a week ago and I have no idea what is causing this error, but I noticed the mouse moves to a certain point on one of my screens when this happens.

I would appreciate any advice: it starts to drive me crazy...

Comment: If you don't have malware or virus on your system, Applications stealing focus is a Windows 7 bug that MS refuses to fix, no one knows what causes it or how to fix it..http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/applications-stealing-focus-reg-key-no-longer/4ee5be7d-31ef-493b-b092-f6f6139f99cd?page=1

Comment: When I have this problem, I use this focus-monitor.exe that I found.  It should tell you which program/process is stealing your focus, and help lead you to your solution:

https://mega.nz/file/4Y8nnbSa#Pnw97sQz8bRM_bXjlrcYT_HGiaBd4kdY_6DNq0T7FWE

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. The Event Log had hundreds of errors in the past hour. I just killed the parent of the faulting dll. I'll probably need to re-install the program for a good copy of the dll if it comes back.

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Application Error
Date:          12/1/2013 9:03:17 AM
Event ID:      1000
Task Category: (100)
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      TV
Description:
Faulting application name: CLMSServerPDVD13.exe, version: 2.2.0.11406, time stamp: 0x51b0297b
Faulting module name: MSVCP71.dll, version: 7.10.3077.0, time stamp: 0x3e77eebb
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0002d90d
Faulting process id: 0x77b8
Faulting application start time: 0x01ceeeaed9275034
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\CyberLink\PowerDVD13\Kernel\DMS\CLMSServerPDVD13.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\CyberLink\PowerDVD13\Kernel\DMS\MSVCP71.dll
Report Id: 16ef8974-5aa2-11e3-80ff-90e6bad417a7
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been experiencing the same problem for quite some months.
Its been quite sporadic and random.
One article that I read (sorry don't have the link) suggested that Dell laptops have this issue.
The problem is due to some bug in the Bluetooth adapter drivers.
So if you are using the internet by Wi-Fi, **turn off the Bluetooth adapter** and see if this solves the problem.
There can be many other reasons for this problem, just wanted to highlight this one among the others.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like there may be something nasty on your machine.

Check your machine for malware with something like [MalwareBytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org/) to see if you have picked up a little bug.

Comment: It wasn't malware: it was a synaptics driver update for my touchpad.