# Applications frequently losing mouse focus

Tags: windows-7, mouse, window-focus

I am programming in Windows 7 and the applications I am using are increasingly losing mouse focus; the system, at times, is unusable as a result. A restart does not solve the problem, Microsoft Security Essentials has not identified any threats, and MalwareBytes is coming up empty. The only "odd" thing is that the ApplicatioLog is full events like these:

`Skipping: Eap method DLL path validation failed. Error: typeId=23, authorId=8086, vendorId=0, vendorType=0`

I am currently downloading any updates I can think of, and have tried disabling Bluetooth [as per this post.](https://superuser.com/questions/271164/applications-losing-focus-for-a-few-seconds-in-windows-7)

What might be causing the focus problem? What techniques can I use to diagnose the problem?

Comment: In case its an application specific error, what apps does this happen with?

Comment: All apps, which leads me to believe it is malware (*hopefully* ruled out by my scans), a driver problem (suggested by other posts), or a software problem (which seems unlikely given that I haven't installed anything new recently).

Comment: Hm. It appears that this doesn't happen when I shut the wireless adapter off. I wonder why that might be?

Comment: is this an internal touchpad/trackpoint or an external mouse? How is it connected?

Comment: It occurs with an external bluetooth mouse, external wireless mouse, and -- I think -- with the touchpad, although I haven't had any recent examples of the latter due to the context in which I use the laptop. I just noticed that a restart of my wireless adapter (Lenovo software) has nixed the issue, and also fixed my frequently interrupted WiFi connection. Perhaps it's the program managing my wireless connection?

Comment: For the first two, sounds almost like interference, especially if they're on the 2.4ghz range. Touchpad... no idea.

Comment: Apologies, meant to say "external **wired** mouse"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by Lenovo's Access Connections software. When the wireless connection is dropped, it steals focus. (I cannot determine in my environment whether it is a bug in Access Connections dropping the connection or if the wireless network is to blame, but it is definitely a response to a dropped connection; if I had to guess, I am inclined to believe it is the wireless environment and not the program itself causing the connection to be dropped.)